# Wierd StaticCompilationError caused by django-static-precompiler

Tags: python, django, django-static-precompiler

On project we use `django-static-precompiler` and `scss`. When I ran localy got this weird error that points to nothing literally. No info at internet or references at docs. I thought it connected to `sass` packecge but it already installed at my system.

[image]

[image]

OR

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just install the newest version